# Sending email from codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter, email, codeigniter-form-helper

I am trying to implement contact form in my codeigniter application. But I get couldn't get it working. I have tried many tutorials, but couldn't find the bug.

My view file.

```
<div id="contact">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="section-title">
            <h1>Contact Us</h1>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-10 col-sm-offset-1">
                <div class="row contact-details">
                    <div class="col-sm-4">
                        <span><i class="fa fa-map-marker"></i></span>
                        <p class="contact-info">1234 Street Name, City Name</p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-sm-4">
                        <span><i class="fa fa-phone"></i></span>
                        <p class="contact-info">+(123) 456-7890 </p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-sm-4">
                        <span><i class="fa fa-envelope"></i></span>
                        <a class="contact-info" href="#">contact@humanity.com</a>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="contact-form">
                    <form id="contact-form" class="contact-form" name="contact-form" method="post" action="contactform/index">

                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="form-group col-sm-6">
                                <input type="text" name="name" class="form-control" required="required" placeholder="Name">
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group col-sm-6">
                                <input type="email" name="email" class="form-control" required="required" placeholder="Email Address">
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group col-sm-12">
                                <textarea name="message" id="message" required="required" class="form-control" rows="8" placeholder="Message"></textarea>
                            </div> 
                        </div>                                                 
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Send Your Message</button>
                        </div>
                    </form> 
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div><!--/#Contact-->
```

My controller class.

```
<?php
class ContactForm extends CI_Controller {
public function __construct() {
    parent::__construct ();
}

// Custom validation function to accept only alphabets and space input
function alpha_space_only($str) {
    if (! preg_match ( "/^[a-zA-Z ]+$/", $str )) {
        $this->form_validation->set_message ( 'alpha_space_only', 'The %s field must contain only alphabets and space!' );
        return FALSE;
    } else {
        return TRUE;
    }
}
function index() {
    // set validation rules
    $this->form_validation->set_rules ( 'name', 'Name', 'trim|required|callback_alpha_space_only' );
    $this->form_validation->set_rules ( 'email', 'Emaid ID', 'trim|required|valid_email' );
    $this->form_validation->set_rules ( 'message', 'Message', 'trim|required' );

    // run validation on form input
    if ($this->form_validation->run () == FALSE) {
        // validation fails
        $this->load->view('_main_layout');
    } else {
        // get the form data
        $name = $this->input->post ( 'name' );
        $from_email = $this->input->post ( 'email' );
        $message = $this->input->post ( 'message' );

        // set to_email id to which you want to receive mails
        $to_email = 'proisuru@outlook.com';

        // send mail
        $this->email->from ( $from_email, $name );
        $this->email->to ( $to_email );
        $this->email->message ( $message );
        if ($this->email->send ()) {
            // mail sent        
            print "<script type=\"text/javascript\">alert('Error: Email Sending Successful.');</script>";
        } else {
            // error
            print "<script type=\"text/javascript\">alert('Error: Email Sending Failed.');</script>";
        }
    }
 }
}
```

And email.php file

```
<?php
$config['protocol'] = 'smtp';
$config['smtp_host'] = 'ssl://smtp.gmail.com'; //change this
$config['smtp_port'] = '465';
$config['smtp_user'] = 'proisuru@gmail.com'; //change this
$config['smtp_pass'] = 'password'; //change this
$config['mailtype'] = 'html';
$config['charset'] = 'UTF-8';
$config['wordwrap'] = TRUE;
$config['newline'] = "\r\n"; //use double quotes to comply with RFC 822 standard
?>
```

I have spent like three hours on this. But still couldn't find a solution.

Comment: Is the e-mail library auto-loaded, or is it just missing from the file (which could be causing your problem)?

Comment: it's auto loaded in autoload file.

Comment: You should be displaying any validation errors if there are any, using validation_errors() helper function is the simplest way

Comment: I have found the article which demonstrate how to send emails in a CodeIgniter application using SMTP. https://www.cloudways.com/blog/send-email-codeigniter-smtp/

Answer (score 0):

In your email config file you specify that you want your emails to be html: `$config[mailtype] = 'html'` but when you are sending your email you set the `$this->email->message` to the forms message input. When your sending html emails in Codeigniter (at least the version I am on) you need to send in a complete web page.

For example:

```
 $data['message'] = $this->input->post ( 'message' );
 $this->email->message($this->load->view('path/to/email/message_view',$data, true ));
```

Then in your view you can do any html you want or just echo out your message:

```
echo $message;
```

[Here is the documentation](http://www.codeigniter.com/userguide2/libraries/email.html)

Comment: The example in the documentation shows a normal string being passed to message() so this is likely not the reason

Comment: @xd6_ This is directly from the documentation: `If you send HTML email you must send it as a complete web page. Make sure you don't have any relative links or relative image paths otherwise they will not work.`

Comment: The reason why the examples pass in regular strings is because the default email type is text. If you set your type either in your config or on the fly to html a string will not work.